# Sizeof(const char **) on 32 bit system

Tags: pointers, char, constants, sizeof, 32-bit

What's the value of the expression above? Is there any difference in running it in 32 or 64 bit (I'm on 32 bit)

Thank you

Comment: 32 bit system, 8 bits per byte, 32/8 = 4.

Comment: This question isn't being seen by many as it's missing the language tag. I'm assuming it's `C` or `C++`. Either way, it's trivial to write code to show this. Assign the result to a `size_t` variable, and print it out to the console. The answer is 4 bytes for 32 bit applications, and 8 bytes for 64 bit.

Comment: Yes, it's a pointer. A pointer to a pointer is still a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value of expression `Sizeof(const char **)` is `8` on 64 bit machine and `4` and 32 bit machine.

**Edit :**

1 byte = 8 bits

`64/8 = 8` bytes and `32/8 = 4` bytes.